# How to iteratively generate all possible combinations of letters and numbers for matching with a variable length string?

Tags: c, algorithm, brute-force

I wish to write a iterative logic program where there is an input string and the program starts from length 1 and tries all possible combinations of letters and numbers. If the match is not found, it tries all possible combinations of letters and numbers for length 2 and so on until it finds a match with the input string.

**For example,**

```
string input = "xG7a";
// loop all possible combinations for length 1, i.e., 0-9 then A-Z, then a - z
// check for all if matches the input string
// loop all possible combinations for length 2, i.e., 00-09, then 0A-0Z, then 0a - 0z. Then 
// for 10-19, then 1A-1Z, then 1a - 1z ... till z0-z9, then zA-zZ, then za - zz
// again check for all if matches the input string
// Keep doing this for lengths 3, 4, 5 and so on till it matches with the input string.
// exit with status success if match else keep going till infinity
// This example would exit at length 4 when it matches with "xG7a"
```

Number of all possible combinations being matched here are (10 + 26 + 26 = 62)  = 62^1 + 62^2 + 62^3 + ... till there is a match.

**EDIT**
More details:

- This is part of an exercise on writing brute-forcing logic
- The input string is not known beforehand. The above example is for illustration. I've figured out the rest of the logic. The generated string is being passed into a hash function that generates a hash to match with a password hash in a database. Hence the dynamic nature of the string to be generated.
- It is known beforehand that the password string is only comprised of numbers and lower and upper case letters.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: when your input string is of length 4 why do you want to start at one, one person can iteratively loop for s.length() time right ?

Comment: The input string is not known beforehand. I'm writing a brute force program as an exercise and this part has me stumped.

Comment: Notice that the pattern you're describing is similar to a numeral system _without a zero_.

Comment: @ForceBru can you elaborate further please? I didn't get the point

Comment: @SaikatDas, you can think of iterating over this sequence as adding one to the current permutation (or, 'number'): `a + <one> = b; b + <one> = c`. The problems arise when you should 'roll over' to generate a 'number' whose length is greater than the one of the previous 'number'. This is the idea I used in my [Woodpecker hash Bruteforce](http://brute.zohosites.com) project. As you can see, with this approach, you can add any number to the current: `a + <two> = c; c + <two> = e`. It's just one of the many possible approaches.

Comment: why don't you use trie

Comment: @ForceBru could you maybe help with a bit of pseudocode? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @HariomSingh please elaborate

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say - a bit of pseudocode, I say - *full working program*!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MARGIN 5

// if you're getting errors due to redeclaration of 'strdup', just remove that
const char *strdup(const char *string) {
    const size_t len = strlen(string);
    char *dst = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));

    memmove(dst, string, len);

    return dst;
}

struct NumeralSystem {
    char *alphabet;
    size_t base;
};

struct Word {
    struct NumeralSystem ns;
    char *data; // the current combination, null-terminated
    unsigned int *_internal; // indices of the characters of 'data' in 'ns.alphabet' 
    size_t length, maxLength;
};

struct NumeralSystem NewSystem(const char *alpha) {
    struct NumeralSystem ret = {strdup(alpha), strlen(alpha)};

    return ret;
}

struct Word NewWordEmpty(const struct NumeralSystem ns, const size_t maxLength) {
    struct Word ret;

    ret.ns = ns;
    ret.data = calloc(maxLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    ret._internal = calloc(maxLength + 1, sizeof(unsigned int));
    ret.maxLength = maxLength;

    *ret._internal = 0;
    *ret.data = *ret.ns.alphabet;

    ret.length = 1;

    return ret;
}

struct Word NewWordPreset(const struct NumeralSystem ns, const char *data) {
    struct Word ret;

    ret.length = strlen(data);

    const size_t maxLength = ret.length + MARGIN;

    ret.ns = ns;
    ret.data = calloc(maxLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    ret._internal = calloc(maxLength + 1, sizeof(unsigned int));
    ret.maxLength = maxLength;

    memmove(ret.data, data, ret.length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ret.length; ++i) {
        const char *found = strchr(ns.alphabet, ret.data[i]);
        if (found == NULL) return NULL;

        ret._internal[i] = found - ns.alphabet;
    }

    return ret;
}

void EnlargeWord(struct Word *wrd) { // here, wrd->length - wrd->maxLength == 1
    const size_t newSize = wrd->maxLength + MARGIN;

    wrd->data = realloc(wrd->data, newSize * sizeof(char));
    wrd->_internal = realloc(wrd->_internal, newSize * sizeof(int));

    memset(wrd->data + wrd->maxLength + 1, 0, MARGIN);
    memset(wrd->_internal + wrd->maxLength + 1, 0, MARGIN);

    wrd->maxLength = newSize;
}

void DestroyWord(struct Word *wrd) {
    free(wrd->data), free(wrd->_internal);
}

struct Word *next(struct Word *wrd) {
    int len = (int)(wrd->length - 1); // this can be negative, see below

    // handle the overflow if current digit is equal to the last_digit of the alphabet
    //   1. last_digit -> first_digit
    //   2. go to previous position
    while ((len >= 0) && (wrd->_internal[len] == wrd->ns.base - 1)) {
        wrd->_internal[len] = 0;
        wrd->data[len--] = *wrd->ns.alphabet;
    }

    // if all the digits in the word were equal to the last_digit of the alphabet,
    // 'len' will be exactly (-1), and the word's length must increase
    if (len == -1) {
        wrd->data[wrd->length++] = *wrd->ns.alphabet;

        // UH-OH, we're about to run out of bounds soon!
        if (wrd->length > wrd->maxLength)
            EnlargeWord(wrd);

        return wrd;
    }

    // if 'len' is still nonnegative, it's the position of the digit
    // that we haven't increased yet
    wrd->data[len] = wrd->ns.alphabet[++wrd->_internal[len]];

    return wrd;
}


int main(void) {
    const struct NumeralSystem ns = NewSystem("abcdef");
    struct Word wrd = NewWordPreset(ns, "deadbeef");

    printf("%s\n", wrd.data);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", next(&wrd)->data);

    DestroyWord(&wrd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the working program @ForceBru. However, I'm still fairly a novice at C and all the pointers are making my head spin. I am following along with Harvard's CS50 course on edx and this particular problem was a part of the following problem set:
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/crack/crack.html
However, I've only learned about looping and other basic decision constructs. I will come back to this program once I have the requisite skills under my belt. Thank you again for the full working program. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with all possible characters in the proper order:

```
 char charlist[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Then for each character you want to check, loop through this string build your test string and compare:

```
int i, found;
char str_to_test[5];
for (i=0, found=0; !found && i<strlen(charlist); i++) {
    str_to_test[0] = charlist[i];
    str_to_test[1] = 0;
    if (!strcmp(str_to_test, target_string)) {
        found = 1;
    }
}
if (found) {
    printf("found it!\n");
} else {
    printf("not found\n");
}
```

Repeat in nested loops for each substring.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves the problem. I'm comparing the entire string. Imagine me hitting a database where a password is stored with all possible combinations. In the above example, the comparison is happening against a single character. However, the program I intend to write should keep on increasing the length of the string till the match is found. The match is happening of the generated string as a whole with the string in the database.

Comment: @SaikatDas Then you would construct the string to check inside the loop using the index of the character list.  I've edited to show how to build the string.  Then repeat with two nested loops for a 2 char string, then 3 loops for a 3 char string, then 4 loops for a 4 char string.

Comment: But, using the above method I would have to write multiple nested loops for each length. I do not wish to do that. That would create a lot of copy-paste code. And it would hit a limit at the maximum number of nested loops I have written. I would like the logic to be such that it keeps looping until it finds a match, irrespective of the length.